# How to write dynamic data in django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want only integer value but string is also being printed in it how do I fix this.

[image]

[image: Output][image]

I want only integer value

Comment: Please share code instead of uploading images of code, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Please do not upload screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
context = {
    'student_fees':student_fees['fees__sum']
}
```